# How can I ignore texts if there is a specific string within a block (awk in Windows)

Tags: awk

#### Question

Can we process strings within a block by awk?

It should only print the `find_me...` text if there is no `error` text between `start` and `end`.

In case there is a text `error`, I just want to skip that block.

Always should ignore the block if it has `error` text, and should print text starting `find` for the other blocks.

Between blocks, new line(s) can be put or not.

#### Input

```
start
some texts some texts..........
find_me1
error
some texts some texts..........
end

start
some texts some texts..........
find_me2
some texts some texts..........
end
```

#### Expected Output

```
start#find_me2#end
```

Comment: This is not quite clear. Is it always `find_me` something? Can there be other words betwen `start` and `end`?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Yes, there can be other texts as well between start and end. I updated question. Thanks.

Comment: What if the second block had `find_me1`?

Comment: I should print that one as well. Updated question again. Thank you.

Comment: Is there always a newline between text blocks?

Comment: Between blocks, new line(s) can be put or not.

Comment: Are you using _GNU_ `awk`?

Comment: Windows doesn't come with awk. Which awk are you using? And where is your code? The StackOverflow community is happy to help you improve your craft, but most of us are not so comfortable as unpaid short order programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *yes*.  The specs as originally posted were not so clear, but you should easily be able to adapt the following to your needs:

```
awk '/^start$/{s=$0; next}
  /^end$/  {if (!error) {print s; print $0; }; error=s=""; next}; 
  /error/  {error=1; next}
  !error   {s=s RS $0}'
```

With your input, this produces:

```
start

find_me2

end
```

(You indicated you wanted the "start" and "end" included, so I've included those, together with the entire block of enclosed text.)

Comment: It seems to be very close my needs. Can you explain about the part [error=s=""] and some explanation about your idea? Thank you.

Comment: (1) error=s="" is just shorthand for error=""; s=""; (2) The general idea is, roughly speaking, to accumulate the lines within a block in the variable s, and to set a flag (i.e. the variable named "error") if "error" is detected within a block.  (3) This script is deliberately confined to awk basics, which are easy to master.  Once you've mastered the basics, adapting scripts like this to the kind of task you have described should be easy.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood that.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an awk solution, here is a (GNU) sed solution:

```
$ sed -rn '/^start/{:a;N;/\nerror$/d;/\nend$/{s/^(start).*\n(find.*)\n.*\n(end)$/\1#\2#\3/p};ba}' infile
start#find_me2#end
```

This does the following:

- `-n` prevents printing unless explicitly instructed to
- `-r` enables capturing groups without escaping the parentheses, `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`

```
/^start/ {      # If we match 'start'
    :label      # Label to branch to
    N           # Append next input line
    /\nerror$/d # If we match 'error', delete pattern space
    /\nend$/ {  # If we match 'end'    
        # Substitute between 'start', the 'find' line and 'end' with '#'
        # and print; this starts a new cycle
        s/^(start).*\n(find.*)\n.*\n(end)$/\1#\2#\3/p
    }
    b label  # Branch to label; we're still looking for 'end'
}
```

And an alternative awk solution:

```
$ awk '/^end$/&&fl{print st"#"$0;st=""}/^start$/{fl=1;st=$0}/^error$/{fl=0}/^find/{st=st"#"$0}' infile
start#find_me2#end
```

Works as follows, a little expanded:

```
# If the line matches 'end' and the flag is set
/^end$/ && flag {
    print str "#" $0  # Print string, append '#' and the line
    str = ""          # Reset string to empty
}

# If the line matches 'start'
/^start$/ {
    flag=1     # Set the flag
    str = $0   # Add line to string
}

# If the line matches 'error'
/^error$/ { 
    flag = 0   # Set the flag to zero, we don't want to print this block
}

# If the line matches 'find'
/^find/ { 
    str = str "#" $0    # Append '#' and line to string
}
```

Comment: That makes me very clear to understand how it works. Thank you!